# What are the boundary conditions for D4-branes ending on D8-branes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, boundary-conditions

In a recent paper by [Cordova and Jafferis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.03997.pdf), they perform the physical derivation of the AGT correspondence. A crucial step is recognizing that the appropriate boundary conditions for the 5D super Yang-Mills are the Nahm pole boundary conditions, physically realized as D4-branes merging into or ending on D6-branes.

I would like to know what the boundary conditions are for the low-energy 5d SYM on a stack of D4-branes ending on **D8-branes**. Has this been studied before?